# VB NET Create a sparse matrix using 2d array

Tags: vb.net

hi guys i have two field in my database. "kode_faktur" as transaction id and "kode_brg" as item-id.. these two fields are exist in my detail transaction table..
so let's says 1 transaction id could have a different number of item-id..
e.g, in my ss below "kode_faktur" 1 has 5 item-id(t1, k4,k9,c2,m4) and "kode_faktur" 2 has 4 item-id(m2,l1,f2,d1)

in my ss below i've already succeed in creating a 2d array (872 rows and 20 columns), where 20 columns is the number that i've acquired from **the max number of item-id that each transaction could have**

i'm using for next looping in this case, i'm using two **for next looping** in this case, i've succeed in looping the first transaction, **but the problem is** = outer of my **for looping** didn't worked. the outer for loops infinite..

for more specific i've included ss below that will explain everything

my requirements here are like this

1. transforming two field into sparse matrix using 2d array
2. binding the 2d array into datagrid

i've already solved the second task. why i'm doing this? because i want to compare this sparse matrix array with another 1d array, create a new one from them, displaying it with grid.

thanks for your attention

regards,me

this is the full code

```
'FILL X

    Dim nil_x As String = "SELECT max( kode_faktur ) FROM detail"
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim CMD_X = New MySqlCommand(nil_x, conn.konek)
    x = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_X.ExecuteScalar())

    'FILL Y

    Dim nil_y As String = "select max(x.jumlah) from (select count(*) as jumlah from detail group by kode_faktur)x"
    Dim y As Int32
    CMD_Y = New MySqlCommand(nil_y, conn.konek)
    y = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_Y.ExecuteScalar())

    'LOOPING ARRAY TRANS
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim arayT(,) As String
    Dim hasil As MySqlDataReader
    ReDim arayT(x, y)

    For i = 0 To x
        Dim msql As String = "select kode_brg from detail where kode_faktur = '" & i & "' "

        CMD = New MySqlCommand(msql, conn.konek)
        hasil = CMD.ExecuteReader()
        Dim row_y As String = "select count(kode_brg) from detail where kode_faktur = '" & i & "' "
        Dim y2 As Int32
        CMD_Y2 = New MySqlCommand(row_y, conn.konek)
        y2 = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_Y2.ExecuteScalar())

        If hasil.HasRows Then
            For j = 0 To y2 - 1
                hasil.Read()
                arayT(i, j) = hasil("kode_brg")
            Next j
        Else
            Continue For
            Exit For
        End If
        'Exit For
    Next i
    conn.konek.Close()
```

this is the ss

[image]

Comment: Already seen this yesterday, but I don't really understand what you are looking for here "*transforming two field into sparse matrix using 2d array*". Could you give an example of how the input look like, and what output you expect from the input?

Comment: @har07 : i've updated the desired output in my ss..

Comment: You need to create a reduced test case for your question/problem. Otherwise it would be hard or impossible to cover in full. For example, instead of `872 rows and 20 columns`, let it be 5 rows and 2 columns. Make up some test case and provide expected results. Also provide the results you're are getting now.

Comment: @Neolisk: i've cleared this question.. it turned out that i need to close the connection every time i create a new one..
thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

To manually create a [Sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) you could do it like this:

```
Dim matrix As Integer()() = New Integer(4)() {}

matrix(0) = New Integer() {1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
matrix(1) = New Integer() {0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0}
matrix(2) = New Integer() {0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0}
matrix(3) = New Integer() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0}
matrix(4) = New Integer() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9}
```

To create one programmatically:

```
Dim ROW_COUNT As Integer = 5
Dim COLUMN_COUNT As Integer = 7

Dim matrix As Integer()() = New Integer(ROW_COUNT - 1)() {}

For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To (ROW_COUNT - 1)
    matrix(rowIndex) = New Integer(COLUMN_COUNT - 1) {}
    For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To (COLUMN_COUNT - 1)
        matrix(rowIndex)(columnIndex) = (10 Mod ((rowIndex + 1) + (columnIndex + 1)))
    Next
Next
```

Result:

```
0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  3,  2
1,  2,  0,  4,  3,  2,  1
2,  0,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0
0,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, 10
4,  3,  2,  1,  0, 10, 10
```

If you want to test two matrices for equality you can create a function like this:

```
Public Shared Function MatrixEquals(m1 As Integer()(), m2 As Integer()()) As Boolean
    If (m1 Is Nothing) Then
        Return (m2 Is Nothing)
    End If
    If (m2 Is Nothing) Then
        Return False
    End If
    If (m1.Length <> m2.Length) Then
        Return False
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To (m1.Length - 1)
        If (Not m1(i).SequenceEqual(m2(i))) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: @roger: thanks for your answer bro..please tell me how to implement your code in my code, cause  i still don't understand your answer, thx u..

Comment: @SoniGunz What do you not understand? The given answer should be sufficient.

Comment: this's the part that i don't understand
    matrix(rowIndex) = New Integer(COLUMN_COUNT - 1) {}
can you explain this part in more detail please?

Comment: @SoniGunz Let's say we define a matrix of 4 rows: `Dim matrix As Integer()() = New Integer(4 - 1)() {}` Why do i increment the value? Because arrays in vb.net are zero-based. This leaves us with the following indices: `0, 1, 2, 3`. At this point, all elements are empty. This will return true: `Dim bool As Boolean = matrix(0) Is Nothing`. So will the next 3 rows matrix(1), matrix(2), matrix(3). We need to populate the matrix array with "columns", and this is the `matrix(rowIndex) = New Integer(COLUMN_COUNT - 1) {}` part. (to continue)

Comment: Let's say we have 3 columns. We then do `matrix(0) = New Integer(3 - 1){}` which is the same as saying `matrix(0) = New Integer(){0, 0, 0}`. This have to be repeated for all rows matrix(1), matrix(2), matrix(3).

Comment: ohh i see..do you mean that i have to define the rows before the **outer loop** and the cols before the **inner loop**.
the example you give me is, without populating array with **database field**, so what if i have matrix of 3 rows. first rows contains **5 columns of item-id**, second rows = **3columns of item-id** and third row has **7 columns of item-id**.
in your example the empty slot is filled with **0**, but what if it were a database field? is that supposed to be filled with **NULL** ?

Comment: in my code, i define the matrix array with transaction ids as a **row** and the max number of item-id that transaction-ids could have as a **columns**..here it's `ReDim arayT(x, y)` . where **x** is rows and **y** is columns

Comment: Yes, x is rows and y is columns. But if you want do have a variable number of columns you'll have to do it my way `Dim arayT()() As String = New String(myCountOfRows - 1)() {}`.

Comment: ok thx @roger, i'll try this right away. and i'll report it as an answer as soon as my prblem is solved..thanks!!!

Comment: @SoniGunz Yup. And I recommend you start creating the matrix manually (for testing), as shown in the first section of my answer, before moving on doing it programmatically. This way you might learn how arrays work. You should also read this: [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).